# .htaccess redirect to a different file only if it exists?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I'm looking for a way to redirect a request for /files/image001.jpg to /files/image001.jpg.php if the php file exists, if not just load the jpg. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you could try it with the .htaccess file and mod rewrite, this should work :

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^files\/(.*)\.jpg$ $1.jpg.php
```

if you want to catch all extensions change the ReweriteRule to:

```
RewriteRule ^files\/(.*)$ $1.php
```

Comment: +1, basically what I had. I think you want the rewrite rule to be this though:  `RewriteRule ^files\/(.*)\.jpg$ $1.jpg.php`

Comment: oh yes, the .jpg isnt catched... but so it should catch all other extensions too: RewriteRule ^files\/(.*)$ $1.php